# Limit memory used by Dask during synchronous computation

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

I'm trying to use Dask to process a dataset larger than memory, stored in chunks saved as NumPy files. I'm loading the data lazily:

```py
array = da.concatenate([
    da.from_delayed(
        dask.delayed(np.load)(path),
        shape=(size, window_len, vocab_size),
        dtype=np.float32
    )
    for path, size in zip(shard_paths, shard_sizes)
])
```

Then I run some processing on the file using `da.map_blocks`:

```py
da.map_blocks(fn, array, drop_axis=[-1]).compute()
```

When I run this, my process gets killed, presumably due to high memory usage (not only is the data larger than memory, but there is also a memory limit on each process).

I could easily limit the memory by processing the chunks sequentially, but that way I would not benefit from the parallelism provided by Dask.

How can I limit the memory used by Dask (e.g. by only loading a certain number of chunks at a time) while still parallelizing over as many chunks as possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to limit the memory used by the process on Unix using the `resource` module:

```py
import resource

resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (max_memory, max_memory))
```

Dask seems to be able to reduce its memory usage once it reaches this limit.

However, the process can still crash on the delayed `np.load`, so this doesn't necessarily solve the problem.